# Archivo PHP ser ejecutado en segundo plano LINUX

Tags: php, linux, servidor

Requiero poner un archivo PHP en mi servidor que funcione en segundo plano y no tener que iniciarlo cada vez que inicie la sesion de un usuario y/o esperar a que expire la misma y tener que volver a usarlo.

El archivo es un socket desarrollado en PHP para que pueda escuchar peticiones cada vez que una controladora le envia un dato al puerto especificado. Por lo tanto requiero lo mencionado con anterioridad.

Algun comando que se pueda usar para iniciar el archivo en segundo plano?

Comment: El "servidor" del socket debe estar ejecutándose previamente, por lo general, ejecutando un comando en la consola, algo como: **php -q socket-server.php** si es que lo desarrollaste en PHP y se requiere de un servidor dedicado o VPS.

Comment: La manera más correcta sería montar un servicio del sistema ( Systemd, SysV,..) de esta manera si el programa rompiese por algún problema el propio gestor de servicios lo ejecutaría de nuevo para q siempre estuviese disponible.

Comment: Mira documentación sobre nohup o screen, comandos de gnu/linux que permiten lanzar un programa y cuando cierras la sesión, sigue en ejecución. Pero como comenta Manuel Barallobre, lo idea es correr el programa como servicio por medio de Systemd o alternativas. Por ejemplo, vas a /etc/init.d, copias uno de los scripts a socket-server.sh y lo modificas a tu gusto. Tienes información adicional en https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20357/how-can-i-make-a-script-in-etc-init-d-start-at-boot

Comment: usa un cron job para realizarlo cierto tiempo

Answer (score 0):

Usa **cron** o **crontab** para ejecutar tareas programadas, puedes usar PHP como un script del sistema solo agrega la cabecera correspondiente `#!/usr/bin/php` y guardalo como un `.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
//Tu script ...
```

> **Información:**
>
> [Ejecutar un PHP periodicamente con cron](https://voragine.net/weblogs/como-ejecutar-php-periodicamente-con-cron-en-un-servidor-linux)
>
> [Cron & Crontab, explicados](https://blog.desdelinux.net/cron-crontab-explicados/)